# WPF Changing ContentTemplate in UserControl by Trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

**Expectations**

My control should appear as shown in [*Figure 1*](http://www.endys.cz/images/tmp/figure1.png). After clicking on the button titled "Second" should contents of the control change, as shown in [*Figure 2*](http://www.endys.cz/images/tmp/figure2.png). In this figure the state should be content again to change back after sending the key Enter the text box.

**Solution**

I created two DataTemplate. These DataTemplates should change based on changes in the properties IsEditable. Default DataTemplate is called ***CompactDataTemplate*** and should be used when the value ***IsEditable*** is equal FALSE.
When the ***IsEditable*** turns TRUE, the ***EditableDataTemplate*** should be used.

File **TestUserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="JP4.Controls.TestControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="26" d:DesignWidth="200" Style="{DynamicResource TestControlStyle}">
<UserControl.Resources>
```

***CompactDataTemplate***

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CompactDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type UserControl}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="First Button" />
        <Button Content="Second Button" Click="SecondButton_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

***EditableDataTemplate***

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EditableDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type UserControl}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Text="Press enter" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

***TestControlStyle*** contains trigger that should firing in case IsEditable has been changed

```
<Style x:Key="TestControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CompactDataTemplate}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditable}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EditableDataTemplate}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

</UserControl>
```

File **TestUserControl.xaml.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestControl
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for TestControl.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class TestUserControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructors
    /// </summary>
    public TestUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Properties
    private bool _IsEditable;

    public bool IsEditable
    {
        get { return _IsEditable; }
        set
        {

            _IsEditable = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsEditable");
        }
    }

    // Controls events
    private void SecondButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsEditable = true;
    }

    private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
            IsEditable = false;
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanging != null)
            PropertyChanging.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;


  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestControl" x:Class="TestControl.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="170" Width="328">
    <Grid>
        <local:TestUserControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,57,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and finaly **MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace TestControl
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
}
```

Hope, now it is clear, what I want. I want to change ***ContentTemplate*** of my ***UserControl***. This change should be fired by trigger that is watching property **IsEditable**.

**Issue**

The **IsEditable** property is changing, but the trigger is not firing. Where is the problem?

*Im sorry for my previous unclear post.*

*All Project files possible to download from same location as Figures just change filename to TestControl.zip (cannot post more than two links)*

Comment: Without a good code example, I don't fully understand what you're trying to accomplish. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Using the code you've provided and trying to guess how you're using it, I could not even get the initial template to be displayed. I.e. the `UserControl` is displayed without any templated data.

Comment: How about [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved!!!**

I just put as the content of my user control ContentControl

```
<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource UserControlStyle1}" />
```

Style of the ContentControl looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="UserControlStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
```

Here is defined default template

```
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CompactStyle}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
```

Here is the trigger that is working pretty well

```
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:PathNavigator}}}"  Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High" Value="{StaticResource EditableStyle}"  />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Of course, I removed the style from UserControl