# Enable and disable an UserControl template programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, templates

I have a UserControl in my application that uses a template like so:

```
<UserControl> ...
 Template="{DynamicResource MyTemplate}"
</UserControl>
```

The template is defined in the same XAML file and it is working fine. My problem is that I do not want the template to be active all the time. I would need to programatically disable and enable it when neccessary.

I have already tried:

```
userControl.Template = null;
```

but this will make the entire user control dissapear.

Any ideas?

Comment: your question is not clear..i hope its like you need to use 2 templates at different times. is that your question?

Comment: Yes, I have done some changes. Ive created two templates in the App.xaml instead of having them in the UserControl XAML. I'm now able to switch between templates. The problem is that I cannot create an "empty" template.

Comment: great.if you have any more doubts please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326813/wpf-changing-contenttemplate-in-usercontrol-by-trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a fully created template, not set it to null. Create an "empty" template, and set it at `userControl.Template = null;`. To check the default templates, there is an answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3527385/1859959).

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

Needed to get the  [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326813/wpf-changing-contenttemplate-in-usercontrol-by-trigger) template of my UserControl.

Thank you @ntohl and @Joseph.